# Define order of bars in ggplot2-generated stacked bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Trying to set the order of bars along the x axis from smallest to largest in a chart with stacked bars.

Data set:

```
MYshop = tibble(basket = c("basket1", "basket2", "basket3", "basket4"), 
                apples = c(10,100, 50, 6), red = c(2, 5, 10, 4), 
                green = c(1, 30, 1, 1), pink = c(7, 65, 39, 1))
```

I believe in order to generate stacked bar chart with ggplot2 it is essential to transform the data set into the long format:

```
MYshop %>% 
select(basket, red, green, pink) %>% 
gather(color, amount, -basket) -> MYshop_long
```

Stacked bar chart:

```
ggplot(MYshop_long, aes(x = basket, y = amount, fill = color)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack")
```

[image: sasa]

I want to order the bars by size, ie by the sum of red, green, and pink (identical to apples in MYshop): basket4, basket1, basket3, basket2

I tried

```
ggplot(MYshop_long, aes(x = reorder(basket, MYshop$apples)), y = amount, fill = color)) + 
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack")
```

but this doesn't work. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it

```
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

MYshop = tibble(basket = c("basket1", "basket2", "basket3", "basket4"), 
                apples = c(10,100, 50, 6), red = c(2, 5, 10, 4), 
                green = c(1, 30, 1, 1), pink = c(7, 65, 39, 1))

MYshop %>% 
  select(basket, red, green, pink) %>% 
  gather(color, amount, -basket) -> MYshop_long

ggplot(MYshop_long, aes(x = reorder(basket, amount), y = amount, fill = color)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack")
```

[image]

Comment: Based on OP requested order, I think it should be `reorder(basket, amount)`, but this works.

Comment: Thanks much! It was right in front of me! I tried multiple iterations but not that one. Cheers!

Comment: @StephenK Very true! I have edited the answer. Dalmuti71 you are welcome

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest next approach formating the variable you use in x-axis based on the total sum of values as you mentioned. I have added a little code to make the aggregation. After that the sorted values can be used to redefine the variable `basket` in your `MYshop_long` data:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
MYshop = tibble(basket = c("basket1", "basket2", "basket3", "basket4"), 
                apples = c(10,100, 50, 6), red = c(2, 5, 10, 4), 
                green = c(1, 30, 1, 1), pink = c(7, 65, 39, 1))
#Reshape
MYshop %>% 
  select(basket, red, green, pink) %>% 
  gather(color, amount, -basket) -> MYshop_long
#Compute sum
MYshop_long %>% group_by(basket) %>% summarise(Tot=sum(amount)) %>%
  arrange(Tot) %>% pull(basket) -> v1
#Format factor
MYshop_long$basket <- factor(MYshop_long$basket,levels = v1,ordered = T)
#Plot
ggplot(MYshop_long, aes(x = basket, y = amount, fill = color)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! helpful but I'll use Jerry424's solution as is simple.